# How can I stop audio playing automatically on a web page?

Tags: html, audio

I am currently working on an website that deals with audio, and I am wondering how to stop my audio from playing automatically when the user visits that page. I have tried multiple ways to embed the audio with methods that should work without html5 and the latest browsers ( and ), and they all play the audio, but they all start automatically, and nothing I have found on Google fixes this. So I am wondering how I could stop the embedded audio from starting automatically, and I would like the solution to work in most browsers if possible.

Thanks for the help.

Edit for request of code I've tried:

```
<embed src="http://www.test.com/audio.mp3" autoplay=false autostart=false />
```

Comment: post the code for some of the things you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `autoplay=false` to the tag.